# Unable to obtain edit token for MediaWiki api

Tags: http, mediawiki

I'm not being able to obtain an edit token for MediaWiki:

Request

```
POST /w/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: en.wikipedia.org
Accept: */*
User-agent: Sbose7890
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=query&prop=info&intoken=edit&titles=Java&format=json
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 09:14:03 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: private
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 209
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from sq34.wikimedia.org
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq34.wikimedia.org:3128
X-Cache: MISS from sq59.wikimedia.org
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq59.wikimedia.org:80
Connection: close

{
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "69336": {
        "starttimestamp": "2012-01-10T09:14:03Z",
        "lastrevid": 469959190,
        "touched": "2012-01-07T11:38:04Z",
        "pageid": 69336,
        "title": "Java",
        "edittoken": "+\\",
        "ns": 0,
        "length": 37800,
        "counter": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried it out using [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/hurls/7189acb2b5b2111069696b783b2f6e61346ac9ce/aad41f17a1477fc5eee00849ab9864ae50e9c11e).

I'm also logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an edit token: `+\`. This is the one for anon users, and is always the same. See [mw:Manual:Edit token](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aEdit_token#The_edit_token_suffix), and also the revisions linked from there.

The problem is that it's regardless of your login, hurl must be logged in. It would have to send a valid `enwiki_session` cookie, yours for example. But do not publish yours, everybody could login with it!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page  That generated an edit token. How does my application obtain the token?  Does it have to specifically send the cookies? ( and can I do that using a console application ) ?

Comment: Yes, when visiting that uri your browser sends your login cookie(s) to Wikipedia. HURL doesn't, where from could it know? You're application will also have to send cookies, didn't you got that in your login procedure? If it's a browser (javascript) app the browser will send any cookies automagically.

Comment: So, I'll need to include client side code ( say, in Javascvript ) to send the cookies. Right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page&format=json   In this case I received the edit token. How did the server receive my cookies then ( as I didn't send it explicitly?

Comment: As I said... the browser does this automagically. Some cookies can be set explicitly (`document.cookie`), but the session cookie is even http-only. It was set by the server when you were logging in.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **do not use the raw MediaWiki API**, there are clients for [every conceivable language out there](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code) which take care of all this tedious stuff for you.  For example, if you're using Ruby, here's all the [MediaWiki::Gateway](http://rubygems.org/gems/mediawiki-gateway) code you need to log in and edit an article:

```
mw = MediaWiki::Gateway.new(your-wiki)
mw.login(user, pw)
mw.create("Article", "Hello world")
```